# Shiny code (graph) works fine locally but gets object not found error on server

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage( 

      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Home",
       titlePanel("2 Degree Portfolio Alignment Dashboard"),  

       sidebarLayout(
         sidebarPanel(
           downloadButton('downloadData', "Download excel template"),
           div(style = "margin-top:30px"),

           fileInput('file1', 'Upload Portfolio Data',
                     accept = c(".xlsx")),
           downloadButton('downloadData1', "Download analysis results"),
           #downloadButton('file2', "Download Result Excel")
         ),
         mainPanel(
           tableOutput('contents'))
       )

      ),  
      tabPanel("Graph", 
       titlePanel("2 Degree Alignment"), 

       plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "400px") ),

      tabPanel("Table", 
       titlePanel("Portfolio Results"),


      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
   )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  mydata2<- read.csv(file='TestData3.csv')
  mdf <- melt(mydata2, id.vars="Emissions", value.name="value", variable.name="Year")

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data=mdf,
       aes(x=Year, y= value, group = Emissions, colour= Emissions))+ 
        geom_line(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +  geom_point( size=4, shape=21, fill="white")+
         theme(legend.position="bottom",plot.title = element_text(size=15, face="bold")) 
   })
```

Works fine on a single file format locally but when I implement in the other file split in server/UI modules on server, I get object 'Year' not defined error.

What is the reason behind object 'Year' not found and how to resolve it? All the code is included here.

Cannot figure out how can that be possible as the melt statement declares the object in both cases. Any feedback will be helpful.

Comment: This is indeed a strange behaviour. Maybe if you share the code of your server/UI split version, it will be clearer and more likely to get answers here...

Comment: UI code:   plotOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "400px")

Comment: Hi, your code appears to be ok... maybe you have another issue... for example... the mdf is empty for some reason... for example...  the original version and the .csv file is in a main folder, but server/ui split version is in a subfolder... if so, it will work if you specify 'mydata2<- read.csv(file='.//TestData3.csv')'...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that is not the issue as I can see contents of mdf in the environment screen.